# C# ObservableCollection<T> equivalent in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In C# there is a class called ObservableCollection, and I need to know if there is any equivalent for Flutter.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `ObservableList<T>` from **mobx** package. This list emits a new event every time it's  updated (inserted, removed, etc.). https://pub.dev/documentation/mobx/latest/mobx/ObservableList-class.html Both provide a reactive way to update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Dart doesn't have.

use setState or Proivder etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).